# Install a second exchange 2010 server

Tags: exchange

First of all i dont have experience on exchange server. But since this is important for the office i have to do it. we have an Exchange server 2010 running in office. We want to install a second Exchange server for fail-over. we have an A record pointing to Mail.companyname.com, We also have two MX record pointing to two mail filter cluster. I suppose our mail filter would be pointing to our exchange host server.
my question is if I want to install a second Exchange server 2010 on the same domain what all changes will i have to make and where. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing I would suggest is get a consultant involved. This is something that you can easily screw up.

You cannot just install Exchange and get failover. What OS is the original server on? If it is Windows 2008/2008 R2 standard, then you cannot do failover. If Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise or Windows 2012 then you can.

So if you don't have the requirements on the original server then you will have to build two replacement servers. You will also need something for the FSW. As for changes, it will not change anything on the primary server, but it will affect clients.

You will need to get SSL certificate, and get host names sorted out. You should also deploy an RPC CAS Array and consider a load balancer.

For someone with no experience with Exchange, this is not something I suggest you do on your own or without a lot of testing. A consultant though would be able to set this up in less than a day.